# Why isn't jQuery automatically appending the JSONP callback?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

The [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) documentation states:

> If the specified URL is on a remote server, the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the `jsonp` data type in $.ajax() for more details.

The [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for the `jsonp` data type states (emphasis mine):

> Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. **Will add an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback**.

So it seems that if I call `$.getJSON()` with a cross-domain URL, the extra "callback=?" parameter should automatically get added. (Other parts of the documentation support this interpretation.)

However, I'm not seeing that behavior. If I don't add the "callback=?" explicitly, jQuery incorrectly makes an XMLHttpRequest (which returns null data since I can't read the response cross-domain). If I do add it explicitly, jQuery correctly makes a <script> request.

Here's an example:

```
var URL = "http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON" +
    "?postalcode=10504&country=US";

function alertResponse(data, status) {
  alert("data: " + data + ", status: " + status);
}

$.getJSON(URL, alertResponse);
// alerts "data: null, status: success"

$.getJSON(URL + "&callback=?", alertResponse);
// alerts "data: [object Object], status: undefined"
```

So what's going on? Am I misunderstanding the documentation or forgetting something?

It goes without saying that this isn't a huge deal, but I'm creating a web API and I purposely set the callback parameter to "callback" in the hopes of tailoring it nicely to jQuery usage.

Thanks!

(Edit: I [cross-posted this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getjson-isn-t-automatically-appending-callback-to-my-cross-domain-url) in the jQuery forums if you're interested.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in the jQuery documentation. See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getjson-isn-t-automatically-appending-callback-to-my-cross-domain-url for details.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var URL = "http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON" +
    "?postalcode=10504&country=US";
function alertResponse(data, status) {
    alert("data: " + data + ", status: " + status);
}
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse',
});
```

Comment: In your example, you actually mean `jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse'`, and yes, that works then without me having to explicitly add the "callback=?" parameter. But that's so much more verbose than the elegance of `$.getJSON()`. It'd be nice if `$.getJSON()` worked as documented...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think you misunderstood. `$.getJSON` is a shortcut for `$.ajax({datatype: 'json'....` as the documentation says. It never makes a JSONP call unless you add the `callback=?` parameter.

Comment: Hmm... did I really misunderstand? The sentence I quoted is pretty explicit: "If the specified URL is on a remote server, the request is treated as JSONP instead."

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code,

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function ( data )
    {
     // do something
    }
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  },
    jsonpCallback: 'login_callback',
});

But, callback sometimes gets appended at the end of the url and sometimes not in IE.
While its working fine in chrome and FF.