# ajax post in azure with ssl error

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2012

i have a web role with mvc 3 on azure with os 2 that is working fine - with ssl

I wanted to upgrade my project to mvc 4 with .net 4.5 so i created a new azure project and copy everything to a new project and everything worked on my station ( I have windows 8 with iis 8 like server 2012).

i upload the new project to azure - with os 3 and everything and my web site is working fine until the code need to create an ajax request with parameters - the ajax request is pending for a minute or so and then i get an error page.

when i remove the https to http the ajax request is working flawlessly.

after investigating and putting traceFailedRequests i saw that iis is rejecting those ajax request.

in the moudle ManagedPipelineHandler i get http reason of unauthorized.

I cant seems to figure what is happening in 2012 server - for now i downgrade the mvc4 to .net 4 and change back to server 2008 r2 and everything is working like a clock.

Does anyone got any idea what can be the problem?

thanks.

Comment: You are experiencing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. What are you requesting from the server?

Comment: nop - its a simple ajax request to get json with data from server

Comment: If it's just grabbing json and you don't mind using jQuery you can try this jsonp hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414899/why-isnt-jquery-automatically-appending-the-jsonp-callback

Comment: the issue in here is not cross domain is something with server 2012 with ssl i think. i get a page from the server - its ok . the javascript is running on the same domain and the ajax query fail. like i said on 2008 r2 everything is working

Comment: If it works with http:// and not https:// it most certainly is a CORS issue which is why it explains that particular behavior.