# jquery ajax callback gets null data

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, knockout.js, jsonp

I'm using knockout.js to bind data in conjunction with jQuery ajax calls to a restful service returning JSON to get the data. I have tried various things on this and can't seem to get the syntax of the call right. When I get the callback to fire, the data is null. In fiddler, the JSON data comes through and the data validates at jsonlint.com just fine. I get a 200 status along with a parseerror in my error handler, while the errorThrown contains 'parseAcademicSessions was not called'.

Here is my code for the knockout view model where the ajax call is made:

```
function HomeViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.AcademicSessions = ko.observableArray([]);
self.hello = 'Hi ...';
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:51044/Rest/GetAcademicSessions',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'parseAcademicSessions',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#academicSessionsDiv').css('color', 'black');
        for (var ii = 0; data && ii < data.length; ii++) {
            if (data[ii].Year < 2012 || data[ii].Year > 2013) continue;
            var beginDate = new Date(data[ii].BeginDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
            var session = new AcademicSession(beginDate.toString("ddd MMM dd, yyyy"), data[ii].CatalogCode,
                                              data[ii].CatalogDescription, data[ii].CatalogYear, data[ii].Description,
                                              data[ii].SessionCode, data[ii].Year);
            self.AcademicSessions.push(session);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
        $('#academicSessionsDiv').css('color', 'red');
        $('#academicSessionsDiv').html("<table class='session-table'><tr><td>Status</td><td>"
                                        + status + "</td></tr><tr><td>JQXHR.Status</td><td>"
                                        + jqXhr.status + "</td></tr><tr><td>Error Thrown</td><td>"
                                        + errorThrown + "</td></tr></table>");
    }
});
```

};

The parseAcademicSessions function is identical to the code in the success function. I've tried various tweaks on this based on other answers here at stack overflow. None seem to work.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: so `console.log` at the top of the success and parseAcademicSessions function would log null?  what happens if you remove the success option and just leave the jsonpCallback option?

Comment: If I get it to hit the callback, the data is null. I've tried leaving out the success option and just using the callback. The parseAcademicSessions function is defined outside any scope so it's global as required by jQuery.ajax. I've also tried something like "window.myCallback = function parseAcademicSessions(data) {..." and "jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'" which fails to invoke the callback as does the syntax in the example. I've also tried no jsonp option with a string name of the callback, and defining the jsonpCallback as a function instead of a string with jsonp: false. No love.

Comment: how bout server side, what happens when you log your data just before it is sent?

Comment: The data looks fine. It is an array of AcademicSession objects prior to conversion to JSON and a normal JSON result object after. I've copied the returned text and inserted it into JSONLint and it validates.

Comment: I've been doing a bunch of x-domain AJAX lately as well.  What I ended up doing was allow requests from certain domains.  Then I can make the request as standard JSON rather than JSONP.  I've never used JSONP so I'm not sure home much help I can be if you're confined to that option.

Comment: May want to check out info [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction) on W3's Cross Origin Resource Sharing - may have something to do with your headers.

Comment: getting null as data in a json or jsonp request usually means the json was an empty string and you're using an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works given what the docs say about [jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but when I take out the `jsonp` option, the following works.  It doesn't when the option is there:

```
var URL = "http://www.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON" +
"?postalcode=10504&country=US";
function alertResponse(data, status) {
    console.log(data); return JSON.stringify(data);
}
$.ajax({
    url: URL, crossDomain:true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse',
 }).done(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

Comment: [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414899/why-isnt-jquery-automatically-appending-the-jsonp-callback).